# Case Sensitive Routing in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does anyone know if it is possible to have Case Sensitive routing in MVC.

I would like as follows to point to different articles.

example

http://my.ie/uRl --> doc 1

http://my.ie/Url --> doc 2

Would love to hear if this can be done.

Comment: I never seen url is case sensitive

Comment: @Murali: really? because IIS is case insensitive, but *nix-based servers for a long while have been (mostly having to do with file system being case sensitive--`foo.txt` differs from `FOO.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Router Constraints and regular expressions like that:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        new { id = @"\d+", action=@"[A-Z]+"  }  //Parameter constraints
        );
```

So, just think about constraints you want to apply in terms of regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Given MVC is an IIS platform (and windows itself is insensitive) I don't know if you're going to have much luck. However, if you're using it to serve up files you can create a fallback route that then takes it a step farther (and parses it appropriately). e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "File_Fetch",
  "{filename}",
  new { controller = "File", action = "Fetch", filename = UrlParameter.Optional },
  new { filename = @"^.+$" }
);

public class FileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Fetch(String filename)
    {
        // /Url -> filename = "Url"
        // /uRl -> filename = "uRl"
        return File(...);
    }
}
```

So now instead of trying to use the routing to differenciate cASe you can interrogate the incoming parameter and serve it up as you see fit.